# Simple webserver unable to refetch web page. Page includes html and large css file like stat.st_size=22926

Tags: css, c, linux, server, tcp

I have created a simple webserver, but I am unable to re-fetch the page twice. In server code my intention was to fetch as many times as the user prefers. I am fetching the page in Firefox browser. I am not saying there is anything wrong with the browser, but there may be problems with my code. So can anyone please tell me what could be the reason that my server is unable to render the page and css again. Is there any mistake in the response header? Why is browser unable to fetch the page?
This is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

//aaa
#define PORT 5000
#define BUF_SIZE 20000

#define SEEK_SET 0
#define SEEK_CUR 1
#define SEEK_END 2

int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b?b:a;
}

int process(int size,char buffer[size],char status)
{
    int i=0;
    int line_len=0;
    char *line=malloc(sizeof(char) *150);

    while(i<size)
    {
        if(strncmp((void *)&buffer[i],"style9.css",strlen("style9.css"))==0)
        return 3;

        if(strncmp((void *)&buffer[i],"GET / HTTP/1.1",14)==0)
        {
          
           while(buffer[i]!='\n')
           {
            line[line_len]=buffer[i];
            line_len++;
            i++;

           }

           //line[line_len]='\0';
           //printf("%s\n",line);
           memset(line,0,line_len);

           line_len=0;
           return 2; 
        }


        i++;
        line_len++;
    }

    return 2;

}
ssize_t sendfile(int out_fd, int in_fd, off_t *offset, size_t count)
{
    off_t orig;

    if (offset != NULL) {

        /* Save current file offset and set offset to value in '*offset' */

        orig = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
       
        if (orig == -1)
            return -1;
        if (lseek(in_fd, *offset, SEEK_SET) == -1)
            return -1;
    }

    size_t totSent = 0;

    while (count > 0) {
        size_t toRead = min(BUF_SIZE, count);

        char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        ssize_t numRead = read(in_fd, buf, toRead);
        if (numRead == -1)
            return -1;
        if (numRead == 0)
            break;                      /* EOF */

        ssize_t numSent = write(out_fd, buf, numRead);
        if (numSent == -1)
            return -1;
        if (numSent == 0)               /* Should never happen */
            printf("fatal: should never happen");
            //fatal("sendfile: write() transferred 0 bytes");

        count -= numSent;
        totSent += numSent;
    }

    if (offset != NULL) {

        /* Return updated file offset in '*offset', and reset the file offset
           to the value it had when we were called. */

        *offset = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        if (*offset == -1)
            return -1;
        if (lseek(in_fd, orig, SEEK_SET) == -1)
            return -1;
    }

    return totSent;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1000] = {0};
    int get_return321;
    //GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1
    char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 Okay\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4 \r\n\r\n";
    //"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n" \
            "Content-Length: 55\r\n\n Content-Type: application/json\r\n '{\"name\":\"fawad\"}'";
    
    
    //struct stat sb;
    char *hello1 = "HTTP/1.1 200 Okay\r\nContent-Type: text/css\r\n\r\n";
    struct stat sb_html;
    struct stat sb_css;     
    int fd_in_html=open("/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/html9.html",O_RDONLY);
    const char* filename_html="/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/html9.html";
    
    int fd_in_css=open("/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/css/style9.css",O_RDONLY);
    const char* filename_css="/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/css/style9.css";

    if (stat(filename_html, &sb_html) == -1) 
    {
        printf("%d\n",errno);
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (stat(filename_css, &sb_css) == -1) 
    {
        printf("%d\n",errno);
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("%lu\n",sb_css.st_size);
    

    
            
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,&opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

       /*if( setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sb.st_size, sizeof(sb.st_size)))
        {
        printf("sockopt\n");
        }*/
        
        /*int state = 1;
    if(setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &state, sizeof(state)))
    {
        printf("sockopt\n");
    }*/
    
    int state = 1;
    if(setsockopt(server_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state)))
    {
        printf("TCP CORK\n");
    }

    

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    
    
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("in loop\n");
    
    
    
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                            (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {

        //  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        
    
    
    
             printf("request came\n");
    
    
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, (1000));


        
        //printf("%s\n",buffer );
        printf("_________________________________\n");
        get_return321=process(900,buffer,'r');
        buffer[499]='\0';
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        
        
        if(get_return321==2)
        {
            

            send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
            //send(new_socket , buffer_html , sb_html.st_size , 0 );

            sendfile(new_socket,fd_in_html,0,sb_html.st_size);
            printf("html sent\n");
            

        }   
        if(get_return321==3)
        {
            send(new_socket , hello1 , sb_css.st_size , 0 );
            sendfile(new_socket,fd_in_css,0,sb_css.st_size);
            printf("3 reached\n");
            

        }
        close(new_socket);
        state = 0;
        setsockopt(server_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state));
        //close(new_socket);            
        state = 1;
        setsockopt(server_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state));



    }
    
    //close(fd_in);
    close(fd_in_html);  
       
}
```

This is the output of running the program and sending a few requests from browser

```
user@fawad:Desktop/C-work# ./a.out 
22926
in loop
request came
_________________________________


html sent
in loop
request came
_________________________________


3 reached
in loop
request came
_________________________________


html sent
in loop
request came
_________________________________


html sent
in loop
Killed
```

Comment: I am using LPI code on sendfile function

Comment: I am not getting css request from browser to server when I try to fetch the page again in firefox. Why is there anything wrong with browser or its just my understanding of browsers

Comment: and cloudflare says `Error 520: Web server is returning an unknown error`

Comment: I killed the webserver And on this link it says `Your web server or networking equipment, any http aware device like Firewall, Load Balancer, et al, reset the TCP connection after it was established. Sometimes when a web server crashes it will reset the connection. Check your web server error logs with your hosting provider for the time that the error occurred to see any error messages.` https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-520-web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error/44205 But I still dont have the solution for this

Comment: `valread = read( new_socket , buffer, (1000));` <<-- you are not using valread. Instead you are using an arbitrairy 900.

Comment: but any solution on this are welcomed https://community.cloudflare.com/t/problem-with-site-css-when-cloudflare-on/4405 because cloudflare not rendering css sent by my server

Comment: and cloudflare error unknown error

Comment: Making obvious mistakes, and blaming cloudflare. Maybe your headers are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. I was not closing file descriptors so my current positions always stayed at the end of files in re-fetch attempts from firefox. Now working this is the full working code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

//aaa
#define PORT 80
#define BUF_SIZE 20000

#define SEEK_SET 0
#define SEEK_CUR 1
#define SEEK_END 2

int min(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b?b:a;
}

int process(int size,char buffer[size],char status)
{
    int i=0;
    int line_len=0;
    char *line=malloc(sizeof(char) *150);

    while(i<size)
    {
        if(strncmp((void *)&buffer[i],"style9.css",strlen("style9.css"))==0)
        return 3;

        if(strncmp((void *)&buffer[i],"GET / HTTP/1.1",14)==0)
        {
          
           while(buffer[i]!='\n')
           {
            line[line_len]=buffer[i];
            line_len++;
            i++;

           }

           //line[line_len]='\0';
           //printf("%s\n",line);
           memset(line,0,line_len);

           line_len=0;
           return 2; 
        }


        i++;
        line_len++;
    }

    return 2;

}
ssize_t sendfile(int out_fd, int in_fd, off_t *offset, size_t count)
{
    off_t orig;

    if (offset != NULL) {

        /* Save current file offset and set offset to value in '*offset' */

        orig = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
       
        if (orig == -1)
            return -1;
        if (lseek(in_fd, *offset, SEEK_SET) == -1)
            return -1;
    }

    size_t totSent = 0;

    while (count > 0) {
        size_t toRead = min(BUF_SIZE, count);

        char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        ssize_t numRead = read(in_fd, buf, toRead);
        if (numRead == -1)
            return -1;
        if (numRead == 0)
            break;                      /* EOF */

        ssize_t numSent = write(out_fd, buf, numRead);
        if (numSent == -1)
            return -1;
        if (numSent == 0)               /* Should never happen */
            printf("fatal: should never happen");
            //fatal("sendfile: write() transferred 0 bytes");

        count -= numSent;
        totSent += numSent;
    }

    if (offset != NULL) {

        /* Return updated file offset in '*offset', and reset the file offset
           to the value it had when we were called. */

        *offset = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        if (*offset == -1)
            return -1;
        if (lseek(in_fd, orig, SEEK_SET) == -1)
            return -1;
    }

    return totSent;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1000] = {0};
    int get_return321;
    //GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1
    char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 Okay\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4 \r\n\r\n";
    //"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n" \
            "Content-Length: 55\r\n\n Content-Type: application/json\r\n '{\"name\":\"fawad\"}'";
    
    
    //struct stat sb;
    char *hello1 = "HTTP/1.1 200 Okay\r\nContent-Type: text/css\r\n\r\n";
    struct stat sb_html;
    struct stat sb_css;     
    int fd_in_html;//=open("/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/html9.html",O_RDONLY);
    const char* filename_html="/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/html9.html";
    
    int fd_in_css;//=open("/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/css/style9.css",O_RDONLY);
    const char* filename_css="/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/css/style9.css";

    
    

    
    //printf("%lu\n",sb_css.st_size);
    

    
            
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,&opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

       /*if( setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sb.st_size, sizeof(sb.st_size)))
        {
        printf("sockopt\n");
        }*/
        
        /*int state = 1;
    if(setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &state, sizeof(state)))
    {
        printf("sockopt\n");
    }*/
    
    int state = 1;
    if(setsockopt(server_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state)))
    {
        printf("TCP CORK\n");
    }

    

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    
    
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("in loop\n");
    
    
    
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                            (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {

        //  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        
    
    
    
             printf("request came\n");
    
    
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, (1000));


        
        //printf("%s\n",buffer );
        printf("_________________________________\n");
        get_return321=process(900,buffer,'r');
        buffer[499]='\0';
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        
        
        if(get_return321==2)
        {
            
            

            send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
            //send(new_socket , buffer_html , sb_html.st_size , 0 );
            fd_in_html=open("/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/html9.html",O_RDONLY);
            if (stat(filename_html, &sb_html) == -1) 
            {
                printf("%d\n",errno);
                //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            sendfile(new_socket,fd_in_html,0,sb_html.st_size);
            close(fd_in_html);
            printf("html sent\n");
            

        }   
        if(get_return321==3)
        {
            send(new_socket , hello1 , sb_css.st_size , 0 );
            fd_in_css=open("/home/fawad/Desktop/C-work/css/style9.css",O_RDONLY);
            if (stat(filename_css, &sb_css) == -1) 
            {
                printf("%d\n",errno);
                //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            sendfile(new_socket,fd_in_css,0,sb_css.st_size);
            printf("3 reached\n");
            close(fd_in_css);
            

        }
        close(new_socket);
        state = 0;
        setsockopt(server_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state));
        //close(new_socket);            
        state = 1;
        setsockopt(server_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state));



    }
    
    //close(fd_in);
    close(fd_in_html);  
       
}
```

Comment: The problem was in sendfile function the current position stayed at the end in my fetch re-attempts from firefox